# Cordova app, using remote website - How to handle connection issues?

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

**My problem**

I'm working on a project where Cordova is being used to display a remote website within the app. Cordova.js is being run from the remote server, etc., and this works pretty well.

I do have one issue though, especially on iOS devices.

If the device lose connection at the same time as I press a link on the website, the page will turn blank, as if to load the next page - but since the connection is lost nothing will be loaded into this blank page. Given iOS devices lack of back-buttons or such there's no way to navigate from this blank page except by closing the app and re-opening it.

**My attempted, and failed, sollution**

So, given that I can use Cordova.js to check for connection issues, I figured that I could use an iframe to display the remote website. If the connection goes bye-bye I'd just display a simple error message inside the iframe.

And well, this does work.

BUT. And this is a big but. InAppBrowser will not run from an iframe. And I can't live without the InAppBrowser, since it's used to display quite a few important features within the app.

**So**

Does anyone know a way to either:

a) Handle connection issues when running only remote content in the Cordova app?

b) Run the InAppBrowser from within an iframe? (I suppose I could use PostMessage etc. between the frames, but since I'm already sending/receiving data from the InAppBrowser I would love to avoid this in order to limit complexity).

c) Solve this issue in another fancy manner?

Comment: Having back button in webview will work for you?

Comment: Don't use cordova to load remote websites. Problem solved

Comment: @jcesarmobile I'd love not to. But the customer is always right, and the customer wants his website to be an app.

Comment: @cjd That's what I'm looking into, creating a native button to interact with the webview. If that's what you meant?

Comment: Then use a regular webview and handle the connection with native code, cordova is not designed to be used on remote pages. Other option is, instead of displaying an online page, download the page code and use it locally (there is a plugin for that)

Comment: @TorClaesson Yes..thats exactly I mean.

 if ([webView canGoBack]) 
 {
        [webView goBack];
 }